# Upload Arduino sketch over-the-air (GPRS SIM900)

Tags: upload, arduino, gprs, ota, sim900

I have an Arduino in a remote location and would like to upload new code via GPRS (a SIM900 is connected to the Arduino via serial interface). I am clueless of how to accomplish this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Maybe even someone have accomplished this already and can share their knowledge?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done it myself, but some googling pointed to this article:
http://baldwisdom.com/bootloading/.

Questions are:

- did you connect all the additionally required lines from the serial port (DTR and RTS)?
- can you use these control lines?

Comment: Thanks for the article.
DTR, RTS and CTS are all connected.
What do you mean if I can use the control lines?

Comment: I meant that maybe the GPRS module doesn't allow to toggle those lines arbitrarily and manages them autonomously.

Answer (score 0):

I had came across [AVR-FOTA-Bootloader v2.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwTKnbVUVZg). The description of the video says

> Firmware Over The Air (FOTA) v2.0 Bootloader for ATmega128 and SIMCOM Sim900 GPRS using UUENCODE by Goran Jurkovi

but there is no other information.

Answer (score 0):

I did it few years back with Neoway modems. Here is the [bootloader](https://github.com/shadlyd15/AirBootGSM) . I modified [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stk500) implementation of stk500 and added TCP/IP support. But unfortunately I do not have the code for remote OTA server now.